# How does a moderation hypothesis looks like?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, interaction

"To examine the proposed relationship between token and 
subsequent support for a cause among consumers with different levels of the two moral-identity components."

Does this sentence imply that moral identity with two levels is a moderator or an independent variable for the relationship between token and subsequent support for a cause?

Comment: It's hard to say. Can you provide more context? Was this copied from somewhere? Where?

Comment: I am replicating a study done by Kirk Kristofferson, Katherine White and John Peloza (2013) titled as The Nature of Slacktivism.

Under the section for future research, the author wrote that "A second factor outside the scope of the present research
is  the  interaction  of  token  prosocial  behavior  with  moral
identity. An interesting direction for future research would be to examine the proposed relationship between token and subsequent support". 

I am not sure whether the author meant it to be a new independent variable to examine the interaction effect or simply keep it as a moderator.

Comment: Please add a complete citation in the body of your question.

Comment: Kristofferson, K., White, K., & Peloza, J. (2014). The nature of slacktivism: How the social observability of an initial act of token support affects subsequent prosocial action. Journal of Consumer Research, 40(6), 1149-1166.